# C# WinRT Type class missing functions

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I'm trying to port some code to WinRT/Metro and I've hit a problem I'm not sure of the work around for. It seems Type is missing the access functions for IsPrimitive and IsSubclassOf(myClass) amongst others. Is anyone aware of how to get this functionality in Windows 8?

Comment: For future reference, MSDN has articles detailing the changes in the .NET Framework for Windows Store Apps.

Comment: Got a link? I've not found anything detailed in my searches

Comment: Sorry, I should have included it before, but I was at work. See: [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230302.aspx) and [2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230232%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those methods are relocated; you need to add a `using` directive:

```
using System.Reflection;
```

then use `someType.GetTypeInfo().IsSubclassOf(...)` and `someType.GetTypeInfo().IsPrimitive`.

(the `using` directive is necessary because `GetTypeInfo()` is an extension method from `System.Reflection.IntrospectionExtensions`).